# Batch: Use first file of type in directory as variable

Tags: java, batch-file

i am trying to write a batch program to find the first file of a given type, lets say a .txt for example, to afterwards pass it to a java program which uses the file name and path to run.

I can already find and check if a file of the type exists but i think i am getting something wrong with the set command and how to handle the parameter afterwards.

```
if exist *.txt (
    echo txt exists
    set file = exist *.png
) else (
    echo No txt file found
    exit
)

echo Using %file%
java -jar MyJavaProgram.jar -%file%
```

I would like to do it without any arguemnts i have to pass in on the command line level and i also can not change the java jar to handle this problem.

Comment: expect your file will be a boolean value?

Comment: Open a command prompt window, run `for /?` and read the output help. All you might need in your batch file is `for %%I in (*.txt) do java.exe -jar MyJavaProgram.jar "-%%I" & goto :EOF` or `for %%I in (*.txt) do if exist "%%~nI.png" java.exe -jar MyJavaProgram.jar "-%%~nI.png"`. It is unclear with which file Java executable should be run and how many *.txt or *.png files exist in directory. See also [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

Comment: The `Set` command does not ignore spaces so currently, you have a variable named `%file<space>%` with a string value of `<space>exist *.png`. The recommended syntax for the `Set` command is `Set "VariableName=VariableValue"`, so I would recommend you use that. Instead of `set file = exist *.png` use `Set "file=exist *.png"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have alluded to, a `for` loop is what you're looking for here:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.txt) do (
    set "file=exist %%~nA.png"
    echo Using !file!
    if exist !file! java -jar MyJavaProgram.jar -"!file!"
)
```

This will loop through all of the text files in your current directory and set each as parameter `%%A`, set the `file` variable as "exist nameofyourtextfile.png", echo your line, then run your .jar with your `file` variable. Exclamation points are needed here since delayed expansion is required to process each text file (in each loop iteration).

If you literally just want to use the *first* text file you come across, you can just make the loop exit with an `exit` or a `GOTO`:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.txt) do (
    set "file=exist %%~nA.png"
    echo Using !file!
    if exist !file! java -jar MyJavaProgram.jar -"!file!"
    GOTO endloop    
)
endlocal

:endloop
```

If I've misunderstood your `set` statement and you don't actually want the word `exist` in your variable (if you just wanted the name) - you can just remove it and the space prior to `%%~nA.png`. If you let us know what specific output you're looking for, we can help you tweak this as necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually just wanted the name like you explained in the comment. Sorry for the confusing set statement, i clearly have to learn about that more. I would like the window to stay open after the java program finished. I would have used a pause but i doubt it is the best was to that either

Comment: It's no problem, and feel free to through a `pause` in there after the loop - they are great for troubleshooting.